# Why is select from sqlx lib executing so long?

Tags: database, go, sqlx

I've got a function which is doing simple sqlx.Select(...):

```
    func filteredEntities(ex sqlx.Ext, baseStmt string, res interface{}, f entities.UserProjectTimeFilter) error {
        finalStmt, args, err := filteredStatement(baseStmt, f)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        err = sqlx.Select(ex, res, finalStmt, args...)
        return errors.Wrap(err, "db query failed")
}
```

Most of queries are going well (10-20ms), but one of them, such as:

```
"\n\tSELECT * FROM Productivity\n\t WHERE user_id IN (?) AND (tracker_id, project_id) IN ((?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?...
```

The query was taken from logs and not formatted. It is executing more than 10 seconds (sometimes even more than 20). However, from a dump of the database, it is executing less than 1 second. The selection has less than 100 rows.  A query even doesn't have "joins" and etc. Just simple "select" with conditions.

Which might be slower? All time was measured by default time.Now() and time.Since().

The table has these columns:

```
+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| id      | planning_id | user_id | activity_id | duration | project_id | tracker_id | created_at | useful |
+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: could you share with us the table's structure with indexes you have?

Comment: @kabanek updated.

Comment: are there more than one server making that request? to the same table?

Comment: If you execute the exact same SQL statement (by copy and paste) at the normal SQL command prompt, does it take the same time?

Comment: @Flimzy nope, literally less than a second

Comment: @whitespace nope, each server has "own" server with db, consequently, to the table too.